# clarification of grid lookup in eloquent javascript ch.7 - electronic life

Tags: javascript

[Eloquent Javascript ,Chapter 7 - Electronic Life](http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html#c_t14rdf0XRH)

Trying to understand the part that describes how to use var grid:

```
var grid = ["top left",    "top middle",    "top right","bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"];
console.log(grid[2 + (1 * 3)]);
// → bottom right
```

Any possible explanations will help. This is what the text offers and I need clarification on: "Or, we can use a single array, with size width × height, and decide that the element at (x,y) is found at position x + (y × width) in the array." Is there another way to re-phrase this explanation?

Comment: You should change the title to be something that describes your problem or your question.

Comment: thanks - just did and put in a better link, any thoughts?

Comment: Thoughts on what?  What are you asking?  What don't you understand?

Comment: trying to understand the logic behind the explanation - can you re-phrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, you are making a 3x2 grid.

Normally, you would do it like this:

```
var grid = [["top left", "top middle", "top right"],
            ["bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"]];

grid[1][2]; // "bottom right"
```

That's pretty simple.  We made a 2D array (a matrix) are are accessing it using `grid[y][x]`.

The example you show is trying to *emulate* that matrix using a 1D array.  Not quite sure why'd you *want* to do that.  It's not as obvious to see what you are trying to do.  I, personally, see **no** benefit to doing it this way.

```
var grid = ["top left", "top middle", "top right",
            "bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"];

grid[2 + (1 * 3)]; // "bottom right"
```

The formula is `grid[x + (y * width_of_grid)]`.  So, why does this work?  Your elements are in groups of 3.  So, you need to find where the group you want starts, that's what `y * width_of_grid` does.  Once you found where the group you want starts, then you add `x` to get the cell you want.

Again, no idea why this would be suggested as an option.  Most developers would pick the 1st option, that's clean and makes sense.  The 2nd one is just confusing and silly.

Comment: Okay, you changed y + (x × width) to  x + (y × width). Let me have a look.

Comment: @RichardB: The "width" they are referring to is the width of the grid you are making, in this case 3.  I mixed up x and y in the explanation.  If you look at the 1st example as being `grid[y][x]`, then it makes sense.  First you go down to the row you want, then you go across to the value.

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to review and explain. Makes sense after reading your explanation.